# Need Drum Machine to work when switch is toggled to ON and OFF

Tags: javascript, jquery

The machine works when the switch is toggled ON but when I switch it off the machine is supposed to stop working when I click on the buttons or press the keyboard. I have tried using if..else statements but it seems like once the switch is clicked my code gets executed on the basis of the event of clicking the button and completely ignores the if..else statements once the button is clicked.

Here is the code:

```
    $("#switch").on("click", () => {
  $("#switch").toggleClass("ON");
  // console.log(document.getElementById("switch").classList);

  if (document.getElementById("switch").classList[0] === "ON") {
    const drumPads = document.querySelectorAll(".drum-pad");
    $(drumPads).on("click", (evt) => {
      // console.log(evt.target.firstElementChild.id);
      // console.log(evt.target.firstElementChild);

      switch (evt.target.firstElementChild.id) {
        case "Q":
          document.getElementById("Q").play();
          document.getElementById("music-style").innerHTML = "Clap 10";
          break;

        case "W":
          document.getElementById("W").play();
          break;

        case "E":
          document.getElementById("E").play();
          break;

        case "A":
          document.getElementById("A").play();
          break;

        case "S":
          document.getElementById("S").play();
          break;

        case "D":
          document.getElementById("D").play();
          break;

        case "Z":
          document.getElementById("Z").play();
          break;

        case "X":
          document.getElementById("X").play();
          break;

        case "C":
          document.getElementById("C").play();
          break;

        default:
          console.log("error!");
      }
    });
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your approach conditionally assigns the click listeners instead of checking the condition *inside* the listener function. Also note that your switch block is not necessary at all; you can simply do `evt.target.firstElementChild.play();`

Comment: Here's one way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/sx1f50re/

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for providing a link to an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that element `#switch` has class `ON` within the event handler for click, or else unsubscribe the event listener when the switch is turned off.

Moreover, your method of checking presence of class `ON` will work only if it comes first in `classList`, which can lead to bugs in the future.

You're also mixing jQuery and vanilla js...

try this:

```js
function handleClick(evt) {
  // console.log(evt.target.firstElementChild.id);
  // console.log(evt.target.firstElementChild);

  switch (evt.target.firstElementChild.id) {
    case "Q":
      document.getElementById("Q").play();
      document.getElementById("music-style").innerHTML = "Clap 10";
      break;

    case "W":
      document.getElementById("W").play();
      break;

    case "E":
      document.getElementById("E").play();
      break;

    case "A":
      document.getElementById("A").play();
      break;

    case "S":
      document.getElementById("S").play();
      break;

    case "D":
      document.getElementById("D").play();
      break;

     case "Z":
      document.getElementById("Z").play();
      break;

    case "X":
      document.getElementById("X").play();
      break;

    case "C":
      document.getElementById("C").play();
      break;

    default:
      console.log("error!");
  }
}

const swtch = $("#switch");
swtch.on("click", () => {
  swtch.toggleClass("ON");
  // console.log(document.getElementById("switch").classList);

  const drumPads = $(".drum-pad");
  if (swtch.is(".ON")) {
    drumPads.on("click", handleClick);
  } else {
    drumPads.off("click", handleClick);
  }
});
```

You could also further optimize your switch statement by directly using the element captured from click target to play it instead of re-searching for it with `document.getElementById`:

```js
function handleClick(evt) {
  // console.log(evt.target.firstElementChild.id);
  // console.log(evt.target.firstElementChild);
  
  const player = evt.target.firstElementChild;
  if (!player) {
    console.log("No player element!", evt.target);
    return;
  }
  switch (player.id) {
    case "Q":
      player.play();
      document.getElementById("music-style").innerHTML = "Clap 10";
      break;
    
    case "W":
    case "E":
    case "A":
    case "S":
    case "D":
    case "Z":
    case "X":
    case "C":
      player.play();
      break;

    default:
      console.log("error!");
  }
}

const swtch = $("#switch");
swtch.on("click", () => {
  swtch.toggleClass("ON");
  // console.log(document.getElementById("switch").classList);

  const drumPads = $(".drum-pad");
  if (swtch.is(".ON")) {
    drumPads.on("click", handleClick);
  } else {
    drumPads.off("click", handleClick);
  }
});
```

Comment: Adding and removing the click handlers is not ideal imo. It's always better to assign them and then just handle the different app states inside them.

Comment: julien.giband thanks for your time but I copy pasted your solutions (both) and they seem to not stop my machine from working when the switch is toggled off. here is a link to my sandbox if you’re interested https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-spence-n2n50

Comment: @user14467240 you're right. That's waht happens when you don't test your code thouroughly! The `handleClick` function was wrongly scoped within the handler for `click` on `#switch`. It couldn't be removed as a handler, as it was redefined every time you clicked your toggle. I've fixed this and tested it with success on your sandbox. Sorry about that!

Comment: Also naming a variable "switch" was not the most clever move on my behalf...

Comment: @julien.giband it works! thanks once again for not only providing a solution but also an improved version of it. Also, I did not know of the .is method in jQuery until now.